# How can I vertically align these 2 divs?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xH2da/), how can I vertically align the image and the text?

HTML:

```
<div class="step_div">
    <div class="step_div_inner">
        <div class="step_div_inner_image">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TasZn.png">
        </div>
        <div class="step_div_inner_text">
            here is some text here is some text here is some text here is some text here is some text here is some text 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.step_div_inner_text {
    font-size:18px;
    width:460px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
    bottom:14px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.step_div_inner_image {
    display:inline-block;
}
.step_div {
    padding:20px 0;
}
.step_div_inner {
    width:574px;
    margin:0 auto;
}​
```

Comment: try to put all these in a table.Or if you want only the image or the text to be centered, put each of them in a separate table

Comment: image isn't showing up in fiddle.

Comment: Here are some tips on vertical alignment: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use floats like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xH2da/10/

You'll just have to make sure to clear them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xH2da/11/

CSS:

```
.step_div_inner_text {
    font-size:18px;
    width:460px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.step_div_inner_image {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2em;
}
.step_div {
    padding:20px 0;
}
.step_div_inner {
    width:574px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align

Comment: Tested on Windows 7 with Opera 12, IE 8, and Firefox 14.0.1 and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best shot...

```
.step_div_inner_text {
    font-size:18px;
    width:460px;
    line-height:18px;
    left:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    bottom:14px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.step_div_inner_image {
    display:inline-block;
}
.step_div {
}
.step_div_inner {
    width:574px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And you can still push around the picture with a few pixel above the image... Depends on the Text and font you are using. There is no definitve answer to your question. But the problem in your particular case, was, that the line height was bigger than the font size.

If you want to stick with your line height, then you'll need to add a top-padding to your image-div until it fits your text... Trial and error :)